# How to skip a json field if it is blank in html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am looking at creating a dynamic program based on json input. I want the program to show headers, subheaders, and choices based on the json. Some of the input won't be filled in. For example:

**Header**
  *Subheader*
     Choice 1
Choice 2
*Subheader2*
Choice 3
Choice 4
Choice 5

**Header2**
Choice 6
Choice 7
Choice 8

**Header 3**
*Subheader3*
Choice 9
Choice 10
Choice 11
*Subheader 4*
Choice 12
Choice 13

```
var json = {"items": [
 {
   "header": "Cancer",
   "subheader": "",
   "choice1": "",
   "choice2": "",
   "choice3": "",
   "choice4": "",
   "choice5": "",
   "choice6": "",
   "subheader2": "",
   "2choice1": "",
   "2choice2": "",
   "2choice3": "",
   "2choice4": "",
   "2choice5": "",
   "2choice6": "",
   "subheader3": "",
   "3choice1": "",
   "3choice2": "",
   "3choice3": "",
   "3choice4": "",
   "3choice5": "",
   "3choice6": "",
   "subheader4": "",
   "4choice1": "",
   "4choice2": "",
   "4choice3": "",
   "4choice4": "",
   "4choice5": "",
   "4choice6": ""
 },
 {
  "header": "Cardiovascular",
  "subheader": "Arrhythmia",
  "choice1": "",
   "choice2": "",
   "choice3": "",
   "choice4": "",
   "choice5": "",
   "choice6": "",
  "subheader2": "Cardiomyopathy",
   "2choice1": "",
   "2choice2": "",
   "2choice3": "",
   "2choice4": "",
   "2choice5": "",
   "2choice6": "",
  "subheader3": "Heart Failure",
  "3choice1": "",
   "3choice2": "",
   "3choice3": "",
   "3choice4": "",
   "3choice5": "",
   "3choice6": "",
  "subheader4": "Hypertension",
   "4choice1": "",
   "4choice2": "",
   "4choice3": "",
   "4choice4": "",
   "4choice5": "",
   "4choice6": ""
  }
]};

var comorbid = document.getElementsByClassName("conditions")[0];
var items = json.items;
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var headbutton = document.createElement("button");
    headbutton.innerHTML = items[i].header;
    headbutton.style.background = '#aeafb6';
    comorbid.appendChild(headbutton);

    var subheadbtn = document.createElement("button");
    var subheadbtn2 = document.createElement("button");
    subheadbtn.innerHTML = items[i].subheader;
    subheadbtn2.innerHTML = items[i].subheader2;

    comorbid.appendChild(subheadbtn);
    comorbid.appendChild(subheadbtn2);

}
```

I've tried removing the choices entirely and I either get an undefined button or a very tiny button with no text.

https://jsfiddle.net/3Lzvjq7w/

Comment: Can the JSON structure be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of your JSON structure it might become hard to check each and every subheader. Your code would be filled with almost identical checks for every key like here below.

```
if (items[i].subheader !== '') {
  // Create button 1
}

if (items[i].subheader2 !== '') {
  // Create button 2
}

if (items[i].subheader3 !== '') {
  // Create button 3
}

if (ite... etc.
```

Now I'm not saying that this would not work, and if you can't change the JSON then this is the way to do it.

**But** if you can change the JSON then you should reformat it like the example below by providing a hierarchical structure. It enables you to add or or remove items from the JSON without breaking any code. You would not have to hardcode every possibility that you would encounter with the `subheader1`, `subheader2`, etc. and can fairly easily be extended.

Check out the result.

```js
var json = [
  {
    "header": "Cancer",
    "contents": [
      {
        "subheader": "",
        "choices": ["", "", "", "", "", ""]
      },
      {
        "subheader": "",
        "choices": ["", "", "", "", "", ""]
      },
      {
        "subheader": "",
        "choices": ["", "", "", "", "", ""]
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "header": "Cardiovascular",
    "contents": [
      {
        "subheader": "Arrhythmia",
        "choices": ["", "", "", "", "", ""]
      },
      {
        "subheader": "Cardiomyopathy",
        "choices": ["", "", "", "", "", ""]
      },
      {
        "subheader": "Heart Failure",
        "choices": ["", "", "", "", "", ""]
      },
      {
        "subheader": "Hypertension",
        "choices": ["", "", "", "", "", ""]
      }
    ]
  }
];

var comorbid = document.getElementsByClassName("conditions")[0];

// Loop over JSON array
json.forEach(function(item) {
  if (item.header !== '') { // Check if header is filled in.
  
    // Create and append headerbutton.
    let headerButton = document.createElement('button');
    headerButton.innerText = item.header;
    headerButton.style.background = '#aeafb6';
    comorbid.appendChild(headerButton);
    
    // Loop over subheaders and choices
    item.contents.forEach(function(content) {
      if (content.subheader !== '') { // Check if subheader is filled in.
      
        // Create and append subbutton.
        let subButton = document.createElement('button');
        subButton.innerText = content.subheader;
        comorbid.appendChild(subButton);
        
        // Loop over all the choices.
        content.choices.forEach(function(choice, choiceIndex) { // Second parameter of forEach is the current index in the array. Like i in a for loop.

            console.log(`Choice ${content.subheader}-${choiceIndex + 1}: ${choice}`); // Log current choice and its value.
            
            if (choice !== '') { // Check if choice is filled in.
                // Do something with the choice.
            }
        });
        
      }
    });
    
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="conditions"></div>
```

**Edit** To access the `choices` array create another loop inside the `item.contents.forEach` function and check each single `choice` if the value has been filled in. I've used the second parameter of the `forEach` method callback to output the current index. Check out more on [how to use this method on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Thank you! I can change the JSON and this makes more sense. My ultimate goal is to have collapsible headers with sub headers that also collapse and the choices as checkboxes. I've done it with hardcoding every value but I would prefer this to be "manageable" for future users. It's been very difficult to figure out how to manage this and this will be my first step being new to programming ;)

Comment: How would you iterate through the choices? I see that you have item and content, do I need to create a third variable and iterate through that?

Comment: `item` and `content` represent the scope that you are currently in. It's like saying: `var item = json[i];` in a `for` loop. I've added the part of looping through the choices.

Answer (score 1):

something like this ?

```
var comorbid = document.getElementsByClassName("conditions")[0];
var items = json.items;
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].header.length) {
     var headbutton = document.createElement("button");
     headbutton.innerHTML = items[i].header;
     headbutton.style.background = '#aeafb6';
     comorbid.appendChild(headbutton);
    }
    if (items[i].subheader.length) {
      var subheadbtn = document.createElement("button");
      subheadbtn.innerHTML = items[i].subheader;
      comorbid.appendChild(subheadbtn);
    }
    if (items[i].subheader2.length) {
      var subheadbtn2 = document.createElement("button");
      subheadbtn2.innerHTML = items[i].subheader2;  
      comorbid.appendChild(subheadbtn2);
    }
}
```

if you don't want to show button if header/subheader is empty...